# Output only first item of field with infinite values (Views, D7)

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-7

I have a field attached to a node "product". The field is of type image and can have infinite images. Now I want to build a view, that lists all products with the node's title and the first image of the field "field_product_images".

How can I achieve that using preferably Views UI? With a Template would be okay too…

I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

In the views UI under `Multiple field settings` you have the option like in Drupal 6, to group the fields, select how many items to display (1 in your case) and what the first item should be (item index 0 in your case). This should achieve what you want.

Views is still in alpha, and the UI especially is a bit flaky, but this should be easy enough to setup.